# How to set up parallel tasks in airflow that run similar set of dependent sub-taks

Tags: airflow

I want to set up following in airflow dag

```
               ---> Env1 Runner--->File1Runner--->File2Runner
main_process |
               ---> Env2 Runner--->File1Runner--->File2Runner
```

There is a main process, which will run two sub processes in parallel for each environment. Each subprocess will run  same series of dependent tasks.
Env1 Runner will set variables for env1 via XCOM and Env2 Runner will set variables for env2 via XCOM.
How do I set up parallel tasks with different value of XCOM variables , but runs same set of functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those tasks are [`PythonOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html), I'd recommend to use an external file as a library that you can import from in the different steps of the process. With that structure, you implement what you want with different inputs (as arguments of those functions), and invoke them from the tasks.

Here's a simple example:

```py
# lib folder > helpers.py
def function_step_1(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    # Do something
    from_xcom = kwargs["ti"].xcom_pull(task_ids="initial_task", key=arg1)
    # Do something with `from_xcom`
    return "something_useful_1"


def function_step_2(arg3, arg4, **kwargs):
    # Do something
    return "something_useful_2"


def function_step_3(arg5, arg6, **kwargs):
    # Do something
    return "something_useful_3"

# DAG implementation under dags folder
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

# This is where you import the defined functions
from lib.helpers import function_step_1, function_step_2, function_step_3

with DAG(
    dag_id="dag_name",
    default_args={},  # Change this
    schedule_interval=None,  # Change this
) as dag:
    step_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="step_1",
        python_callable=function_step_1,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={
            "arg1": "something1",
            "arg2": "something2",
        },
    )

    step_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="step_2",
        python_callable=function_step_2,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={
            "arg3": "something3",
            "arg4": "something4",
        },
    )

    step_3 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="step_3",
        python_callable=function_step_3,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={
            "arg5": "something5",
            "arg6": "something6",
        },
    )

    # You're going to add two of this starting with an initial task
    step1 >> step2 >> step3
```

In the function `function_step_1` you'll process the `XCom` from the first task. You can use one argument to differentiate which `key` are you going to use from `XCom` (I included an example of how to consume it).

Comment: Is initial_task referred in function _step_1 same as main_process in the question?
If yes , then I have to create different steps for each environment using same functions but with different input argument

Comment: Yes, exactly. My example was generic, but definitely you can map `initial_task` in the example with `main_process` in the question. The steps are different for each environment since you need to set the argument to differentiate between `XCom` pulls.

Comment: @user3376169, would be very useful if you also upvote the question if it was helpful :) Thanks.